# Add extra field to a file for records that have 6 fields instead of 7

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a problem with text files separated by commas, when I'm going to begin receiving files (hundreds of them) with a mixed layout, some records will have 7 fields(a total of 6 commas) and other records in the same file will have 6 fields (a total of 5 commas).

When I find a record with 5 commas, I want to add at the end of that record a comma followed by NA so my loading process thinks it has 7 fields, being the last one NA.

This is what I have right now, the first record has 7 fields, the second only 6:

```
200000003183000100,Data,NA,0,IN,0,0.00
200000004625000000,Data,NA,0,IN,0
```

This is what I expect (both records with 7 fields)

```
200000003183000100,Data,NA,0,IN,0,0.00
200000004625000000,Data,NA,0,IN,0,NA
```

Can this be done counting commas with sed or something similar and adding at the end of the file ,NA whenever there's only 5 commas. Please keep in mind this is going to happened for hundreds of files, so I don't know if I need to use the filename as a parameter so something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency in awk, don't modify the record (`$0`) or fields (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) unless you have to. This doesn't modify either of them:

```
awk -F, '{print $0 (NF==6 ? ",NA" : "")}'
```

The other existing awk answers either modify $0 or modify fields, either of which slow down processing.

These directly change $0 (and so indirectly add a field):

```
awk -F, 'NF==6{$0=$0",NA"}1'
awk '/(.*,){6}/ || sub(/$/,",NA")'
awk '!/(.*,){6}/{$0=$0",NA"}1'
```

which requires awk to find new memory for `$0` to move into due to it's increased size (concatenating to or otherwise changing the size of a variable is one of the slowest operations in awk) and causes awk to resplit `$0` into fields.

These directly change fields (and so indirectly change $0):

```
awk -F, -v nf=7 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } (NF < nf){ $(nf)="N/A"}1'
awk -F, -v nf=7 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { for (i = NF+1; i <= nf; ++i ) $i = "NA" }; 1'
```

which causes awk to rebuild `$0` from it's fields, and once again requires awk to find new memory for `$0` to move into due to it's increased size

To run any awk script on hundreds (but fewer than would exceed ARG_MAX) of CSV files using GNU awk is just:

```
awk -i inplace 'script' file*.csv
```

or with any awk:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
for file in file*.csv; do
    awk 'script' "$file" > "$tmp" &&
    mv -- "$tmp" "$file"
done
```

Comment: You're so right about performance. They sent me today more than 2.5K files (and the files have 110 or 111 fields, I just said 5 or 6 so the example was easier to do) And I had to do it like this because after half hour the previous awk I used wasn't finishing. This took less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 8):

If [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is allowed:

```
awk -F, 'NF==6{$0=$0",NA"}1' file
```

Comment: You might want to explain that the output will need to be redirected to a new file and the new file renamed back to the original (the OP mentions hundreds of files), or if this is for GNU awk, the `-i inplace` option.

Comment: Thanks Gilles that was the missing piece. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [Gilles Quenot's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704400/116858), but adds the new field as a new field rather than as a string at the end of the current line.  Additionally, allows both the delimiter and the expected number of fields to be configured on the command line and will fill out the missing fields with the string `NA`:

```bash
$ awk -F , -v nf=7 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { for (i = NF+1; i <= nf; ++i ) $i = "NA" }; 1' file
200000003183000100,Data,NA,0,IN,0,0.00
200000004625000000,Data,NA,0,IN,0,NA
```

```bash
$ awk -F , -v nf=12 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { for (i = NF+1; i <= nf; ++i ) $i = "NA" }; 1' file
200000003183000100,Data,NA,0,IN,0,0.00,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
200000004625000000,Data,NA,0,IN,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
```

This obviously assumes that the input is in *simple CSV* format (does not contain fields with embedded commas or newlines).

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to do something like `awk -F, -v nf=7 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } (NF < nf){ $(nf)="N/A"}1' file` instead of iterating over the fields?

Comment: @terdon Sure, it would be, if you only ever need to fill out a single field at the end.

Comment: Ah, of course. I hadn't thought of the case where you'd be adding more than one field.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```bash
$ sed -E '/^([^,]+,){5}[^,]+$/s/$/,NA/' file 
200000003183000100,Data,NA,0,IN,0,0.00
200000004625000000,Data,NA,0,IN,0,NA
```

Answer (score 2):

`Posix sed`, we try changing the 6th comma, and if we succeed we print and go back reading the next record (test command **t** )
Otherwise, append the `,NA` string to the end of current record.

```bash
sed '
  s/,/,/6;t
  s/$/,NA/
' file
```

---

Using `awk`, one way is:

```
awk '/(.*,){6}/ || sub(/$/,",NA")' file
```

---

The use case when you need to do this operation for multiple files is via the `find` command.

Assuming your CSV files are named `*.csv`

```bash
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec \
  sed -i 's/,/,/6;t' -e 's/$/,NA' {} +
```

---

For the case of awk, use the inplace option if your awk supports it (GNU awk version 4.1.0 onwards)

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.csv" -exec \
awk -i inplace '!/(.*,){6}/{$0=$0",NA"}1' {} +
```

---

The symbol **{} +** funnels multiple filenames to the awk or sed commandlines, so that the invocation of these utilities is minimized

Notes:

- The file has either 5 or 6 commas.
- The fields themselves cannot contain a comma(s).
- Line endings are linux style (\n).

Comment: The awk works like a charm, but how can I do this for hundred of files instead of one by one?

Comment: Updated to address your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly and is exactly wahat I was looking for.